# Jersey - Determine "@Produces" using Context?

Tags: java, http-headers, jersey

I'm new to Jersey, and want to determine the `@Produces` type in other contexts, so I can use it during error handling cases.

For example, I have the following method that produces json:

```
@Path("test-json")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@GET
public Object getTestJson(@Context HttpServletRequest req, @Context HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception
{
        throw new RuntimeException("POST submitted without CSRF token! ");
}
```

Later on, in a global exception  handler, I'd like to get the `@Produces` media type.
I've tried doing this with something like the following, but `getMediaType()` is returning null (note that this is simplified, but headers is not null in all of my tests, just `getMediaType()` is null).

```
public class someClass
{
    @Context
    HttpHeaders headers;

    public Response convertExceptionToResponse(T exception)
    {
         MediaType mediaType = headers.getMediaType();

         // At this point, I thought media type would be 
         //    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON 
         // for the above 'getTestJson' method, but it's null. 
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### JAX-RS

Inject [ResourceInfo](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceInfo.html) and invoke [getResourceMethod()](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceInfo.html#getResourceMethod%28%29) which will return Java [Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html). Then you can simple retrieve declared annotations. The problem here is that with this approach you need to do a lot of coding in case `@Produces` is not located directly on a method but somewhere in the hierarchy.

#### Jersey 2

Inject [ExtendedUriInfo](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ExtendedUriInfo.html)

```
@Context
private ExtendedUriInfo uriInfo;
```

and look for matched [ResourceMethod](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/model/ResourceMethod.html) ([getMatchedResourceMethod()](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ExtendedUriInfo.html#getMatchedResourceMethod%28%29)). Then simply get list of producible media types ([getProducedTypes()](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/model/ResourceMethod.html#getProducedTypes%28%29)).